# how to bootstrap data on irregular grid?

Tags: bootstrap, spatial

I have irregular gridded data and I wish to resample from this data in such a way that the spatial correlation in the data is preserved. I will assume that grids that are within 300Kms of one another are correlated. I have 153 grids in all and some grids have 2 neighbours (i.e. 2 grids that lie within 300 kilometres) and some grids have as many as 11 neighbours. I wish to know how to draw a bootstrap sample from this grid. My ultimate objective is to run a regression on the gridded data that I have to get at the distribution of the standard error of the regression coefficient. Many thanks!

Comment: After bootstrapping, some will even have "neighbours" at 0 km.

Comment: All grids have neighbours some just have too many and some little.

Comment: For this you typically have blocks of data removed at once (aptly called [block bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28statistics%29#Block_bootstrap)), so there are sufficient other observations with nearby neighbors to reliably calculate whatever spatial statistics. (Another common approach is to do leave-one-out resampling.)